# Building Android APK in gitlab w/ auto download of android sdk

Tags: android, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, github-actions

I have an Android project currently building an APK in github actions:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - name: Setup JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '11'
    - name: Build Application
      run: |
        ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Translated to this in GitLab:

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  image: openjdk:11
  stage: build
  when: manual
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
```

In GitHub build I am getting an error:

```
SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable
```

What I don't understand is that I cannot find anything in my GitHub build where it downloads the Android SDK.  Why is this build working in GitHub but not GitLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK is included in the [preinstalled software](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md#android) on GitHub-hosted Actions runner. That's why you don't have to install it in the case when you are using GitHub.

In GitLab, you are using the `openjdk:11` image for your job. The Android SDK is not installed in the `openjdk:11` image. To deal with this, you could change the `image:` parameter in your job to use an image with the SDK already installed or install the SDK as part of your job.

Comment: Whelp, that is exactly the "magic" step that I was failing to find.  Thank you.